# Length of curve - Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, curves

I need to find the LENGTH of the curve with x,y,z components listed below:

$ x(t) = t\sin(2t)$

$ y(t) = t\cos(2t)$

$z(t) = (4/3)t\sqrt(t) = (4/3)(t^{1.5})$

from $t= 0$ to $t=2\pi$

can anyone help pls? i have tried but came to a very hard integral which doesnt look right

i get

$L =2 \int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{t^2 + t}$

which looks wrong since the online solution to this is very lengthy.

Comment: SORRY I MEANT LENGTH NOT AREA

Comment: please show your working. The integrand simplifies.

Comment: @DavidQuinn i updated it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the formula of the length of a curve: $\int ||\varphi|| dt$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.
in this case the derivative of the components are: 
$$x'=\sin{(2t)} + 2t\cos{(2t)}$$
$$y'=\cos{(2t)}- 2t\sin{(2t)}$$
$$z'=2t^{0.5}$$

follows that the function as an integral is $2t+1$ because $2t+1$ is positive in $[0,2\pi]$. And now this integral is very easy.

Comment: did you use  $\int \sqrt{{x'}^2 +{y'}^2 +{z'}^2}$?

Comment: because i obtain $2\int \sqrt {t^2 +t} $

Comment: yes I used it.  Under the root I obtain (2t+1)^2